# Playing PSN bought games on separate PSN account

Tags: ps3, psn, region-lock

I am thinking of buying a couple PS3 PSN games from the US PSN with a US PSN account since they're having a sale.

I download the games, and then switch accounts to my main (Australian) account, would I still be able to play them and earn trophies etc?

Comment: You could try this with a free game/demo from the US store. Preferable one that isn't available in your store.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As long as you've "activated" your console with the secondary account, you may use the games and DLC bought in it by different users on the same console.

There may be some exceptions to this (I know of a single game and a couple of DLC), but to be on the safe side, on the store's product page, look for the disclaimer

> One time fee for use of downloads on up to 2 activated compatible Home Console systems.

For comparison, here's what the disclaimer on a "single user" game looks like:

> One time fee for use of downloads solely **by the purchasing Sony Entertainment Network account** on up to 2 activated compatible Home Console systems. No more than 1 activated compatible Home Console system within a 24 hour period. Content may not be used by any other account. You must sign in to PSN each time you start the game.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Hey @Robotnik, we had conflicting edits but I've taken your input, thanks :)

Comment: cool no worries :)

Comment: I'm at work so I can't test and say with 100% certainty, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't work for accounts from separate regions. I know some people who have multiple PSN accounts just so they can play games from the US/EU/JAP store, and they have to switch accounts to actually play the game, not just to buy it.

Comment: I have accounts from three different regions and never had any problems playing games between then